# Convert Hijri Shamsi date format tsql

Tags: t-sql, date, hijri

I want convert my Hijri Shamsi date **'92/2/3'** to this format : **'92/02/03'**

With this code, I get this error :**The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.**

```
Declare @Str Varchar(10) = '92/2/3'
Select Convert(Varchar(10), Convert(DateTime, @Str), 111)
```

How can i change format of date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since you don't have centuries you should use `11`, not `111` as your conversion code
2. You need to use 11 in the inner convert to tell it what format it is converting FROM

   ```
   Declare @Str Varchar(10) = '92/2/3'    
   Select Convert(Varchar(10), Convert(DateTime, @Str,11), 11)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use this functions to convert Gregorian date to Hijri(Shamsi) date with your requested format:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ShamsiDate]
        (
          @ChirsDate SMALLDATETIME
        )
    RETURNS CHAR(10)
    AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @SolarDate CHAR(10)
            DECLARE @Day CHAR(2)
            DECLARE @Mon CHAR(2)
            DECLARE @SDay INT
            DECLARE @SMon INT
            DECLARE @SYear INT
            SET @SYear = dbo.ShamsiDatePart(@ChirsDate, 'Y')
            SET @SMon = dbo.ShamsiDatePart(@ChirsDate, 'M')
            SET @SDay = dbo.ShamsiDatePart(@ChirsDate, 'D')
            IF @SMon <= 9
                SELECT  @Mon = '0' + CONVERT(CHAR(1), @SMon)
            ELSE
                SELECT  @Mon = CONVERT(CHAR(2), @SMon)
            IF @SDay <= 9
                SELECT  @Day = '0' + CONVERT(CHAR(1), @SDay)
            ELSE
                SELECT  @Day = CONVERT(CHAR(2), @SDay)
            SELECT  @SolarDate = CONVERT(CHAR(4), @SYear) + '/' + @Mon + '/'
                    + @Day
            RETURN @SolarDate
        END

    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ShamsiDatePart]
        (
          @MiDate DATETIME ,
          @ADatePart CHAR
        )
    RETURNS INT
    AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @TmpY INT ,
                @Leap INT
            DECLARE @Sh_Y INT ,
                @Sh_M INT ,
                @Sh_D INT ,
                @Result INT
            IF @MiDate IS NULL
                RETURN 0
            DECLARE @Result INT
            SET @Result = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(FLOAT, @MiDate))
            IF @Result <= 78
                BEGIN
                    SET @Sh_Y = 1278
                    SET @Sh_M = ( @Result + 10 ) / 30 + 10
                    SET @Sh_D = ( @Result + 10 ) % 30 + 1
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @Result = @Result - 78
                    SET @Sh_Y = 1279
                    WHILE 1 = 1
                        BEGIN
                            SET @TmpY = @Sh_Y + 11
                            SET @TmpY = @TmpY - ( @TmpY / 33 ) * 33
                            IF ( @TmpY <> 32 )
                                AND ( ( @TmpY / 4 ) * 4 = @TmpY )
                                SET @Leap = 1
                            ELSE
                                SET @Leap = 0
                            IF @Result <= ( 365 + @Leap )
                                BREAK
                            SET @Result = @Result - ( 365 + @Leap )
                            SET @Sh_Y = @Sh_Y + 1
                        END
                    IF @Result <= 31 * 6
                        BEGIN
                            SET @Sh_M = ( @Result - 1 ) / 31 + 1
                            SET @Sh_D = ( @Result - 1 ) % 31 + 1
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            SET @Sh_M = ( ( @Result - 1 ) - 31 * 6 ) / 30 + 7
                            SET @Sh_D = ( ( @Result - 1 ) - 31 * 6 ) % 30 + 1
                        END
                END
            RETURN CASE @ADatePart WHEN 'Y' THEN @Sh_Y WHEN 'M' THEN @Sh_M WHEN 'D' THEN @Sh_D ELSE 0 END
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the give below solution, if you are using SQL Server 2012.

```
Declare @Str varchar(10) = '92/2/3'    
Select Format(Convert(Date, @Str,11),'yy/MM/dd')
```

Imran